Start a new container for each connection to containerized Azure web app
I have a containerized Azure web app which is accessed from an azurewebsite.net URL. The docker image executes an R shiny app. If someone launches a long running calculation in the app other users are unable to connect until the calculation is finished. Is it possible to cause a new image to execute when another user opens the application? Then all the sessions would be independent and would not interfere with each other. I have tried different horizontal and vertical scaling options but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Refer this SO Answer you can enable Pre-site-scaling to scale the web app and adding the number of workers more than 1 to load balance your app across 2 worker instances in the same app service plan.
Powershell commands:-
Reference- MS Document
$resourceGroup="siddheshrg"
$appServicePlan="siddheshappser65"
$location="EastUS"

New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $appServicePlan -Location $location -Tier Premium -WorkerSize Small -NumberofWorkers 5 -PerSiteScaling $true

#For existing app:-
Set-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $AppServicePlan -PerSiteScaling $true


Now, Add the number of workers the apps will run on:-
$newapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $webapp
$newapp.SiteConfig.NumberOfWorkers = 2
Set-AzWebApp $newapp

You can also implement session states in the existing Docker image, so that the app access is independent of the user:-
shinymanager package can be used for session management:-
FROM rocker/r-ver:latest

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'shinymanager'), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"

COPY my_shiny_app /srv/shiny-server/my_shiny_app

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp(host='0.0.0.0', port=3838)"]

